# How can I create a designated init for a grouped style UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have this UITableViewController subclass:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let foo: String

    init(foo: String, style: UITableViewStyle = .Grouped) {
        self.foo = foo
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }
}
```

Nothing fancy, unfortunately it does not work as expected because `super.init(style: style)` will invoke `MyTableViewController(nibName:bundle:)`. But that's not implemented in my class, so the app will crash with a `fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class` error.

Obviously the correct way is to call the designated initializer. Unfortunately `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` will create a plain style tableView.

I could turn `let foo: String` into `var foo: String!` and turn my designated initializer into a convenience initializer. Like this:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var foo: String!

    convenience init(foo: String, style: UITableViewStyle = .Grouped) {
        self.init(style: style)
        self.foo = foo
    }
}
```

Which will work, but it defeats the purpose of `let`. So I don't want to do this.

---

What am I doing wrong? What do I have to do to be able to use my own initializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is of course to call the designated initializer. But to get a Grouped Style TableView you have to use a nib file.

This nib contains a grouped UITableView. The File Owner of the nib file is a UITableViewController. Its view outlet is connected to the UITableView. Pretty straight forward.

We can then use the following code as our init method:

```
init(foo: String, style: UITableViewStyle = .Grouped) {
    self.foo = foo

    if style == .Grouped {
        super.init(nibName: "GroupedTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    }
    else {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

It's not very elegant but it gets the job done.