# Subclassing UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I subclassed a UITableViewController in Swift and added a custom initializer:

```
init(scheduleController: ScheduleController) {
    self.scheduleController = scheduleController
    super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    self.title = "Routes"
}
```

now when I start the app it crashes with:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'Shuttle_Plan.RoutesViewController'
```

How can I solve this without adding this initializer?

Comment: You cannot solve it "without adding this initializer". Add it.

Comment: I can't add the initializer, because it does not know anything about the properties that need to be assigned before calling super.init

Comment: You must adjust to that. Show more of the code (e.g. the properties and your other initializers) and I'll add that to my answer. But you have no choice, you must do what it says or you will crash. It isn't your fault but you must do it.

Comment: Or make the properties Optionals.

Comment: maybe that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388951/how-can-i-create-a-designated-init-for-a-grouped-style-uitableviewcontroller Since you use .Plain you can just use `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` instead of `super.init(style:...)`

Comment: I agree, I'm just adding that now, @MatthiasBauch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maddening, isn't it? But the error message tells you what to do: *if* you are going to call `super.init(style:)`, *then* you must also implement `init(nibName:bundle:)`, even if all you do there is to call `super`:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName:nibNameOrNil, bundle:nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

This, however, raises the question of what to do about properties. Swift won't let you implement `init(nibName:bundle:)` unless it initializes all uninitialized properties.

- One obvious solution is to make your properties Optionals; now the implementation shown above is legal. In `init(scheduleController:)`, you will have to initialize your properties *after* calling `super.init`.
- Less dramatically, make your property a `var` but not an Optional. Now initialize it multiple times: before `super.init` in all your initializers, and also *after* `super.init` in your `init(scheduleController:)`.

None of those, however, are the solution I use in my own code. In my code, I do *not* call `super.init(style:)`, as you are doing — I call `super.init(nibName:bundle:)` instead. This works because:

- The default style is `.Plain`, which is what you want
- Even if what you want is `.Grouped`, you can specify that in the associated nib file

The big advantage of this approach is that it permits your properties to be a non-Optional `let`, which is probably what you really would like to do.

Comment: The reason for this sort of thing is explained in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_surprises_from_cocoa

Comment: Basically what's happening is that the Cocoa APIs do not obey the same rules as Swift initializers: the initializer `init(style:)` behaves like a convenience initializer in that it calls `init(nibName:bundle:)`, but it is not _marked_ as a convenience initializer. I do not deny for a moment that this situation is insane. You have a good use case and should file a bug report.

Comment: calling super.init(nibName:bundle:) did the trick. Still it feels like a hack.

Comment: "Still it feels like a hack" Definitely! They are all hacks. Cocoa's behavior is wrong (as far as Swift is concerned) and you are caught in the crossfire. So do whatever it takes.